# Encoding special characters in c#

Tags: c#, encoding

In my c# application, i receive post data in the form of xml. Within the xml i have a attribute receiving as " `SmÃ¥senter (Sandvika SmÃ¥senter)`" . Before inserting to database i need to encode it as "`Småsenter (Sandvika Småsenter)`" . I tried to use below code ,

```
string name = "SmÃ¥senter (Sandvika SmÃ¥senter)";
name = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(name);
```

Also tried `name = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(name);`

But it is not giving expected output.
Is any suggessions to get in expected characters.

Regards

Sangeetha

Comment: It sounds like your XML is simply broken to start with - why doesn't it encode the character correctly? What's creating this XML, and how are you parsing it?

Comment: Does the header of your xml document specify the encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have just encountered [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), which is caused by mixing text encodings. You need to use the same encoding for writing and reading the XML, preferably a Unicode encoding such as UTF-8. You should not try to repair a broken string such as "SmÃ¥senter", but rather make it not break in the first place.

Comment: +1, it is also impossible to automatically detect the encoding with 100% success, ie has such an algorithm but it sometimes fails to find the right encoding